# Send Selected DropDownList value to HomeController ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model, actionresult

Hi I have a drop down list that is filled in from comma delimited values in the config. This works fine.

What I am trying to do is to send the selected value on button click to a ActionResult in the HomeController.

I created a Model, which is taking a string. When I hit the button I get error:

> The view 'TestAction' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

This is what my Controller looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("TestAction")]
    public ActionResult TestAction(SQL_Blocks_App.Models.DropdownList SelectedValue)
    {

        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(SelectedValue);



        return View();
    }
```

This is what my model looks like:

```
public class DropdownList
{
    //
    // GET: /DropdownList/
    [Display(Name = "Servers")]
    public string SelectedValue{ get; set; }



}
```

and this is what my Index View looks like:

```
    <form id="SelectedValue" action="/Home/TestAction" method="post" style="margin: 0">
       <div class="col-lg-5">
            @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
            }
            @Html.DropDownList("YourElementName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropdownVals, "--Choose Your Value--", new

            {

               //size = "5",
               style = "width: 600px"

            })


        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <input type="submit" value="Run Query" />

            <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="window.location.reload()" />

        </div>
    </form>
```

I want to clarify. My end goal is to use the selected value in a SQL query in the ActionResult and return the results back to the index so I can fill them in a table. ( You don't have to show me how to do the SQL part for now I just would like to see the selected value at least printed in the output.)

Comment: Quick question about your View:  Why are you explicitly building the Form instead of: "@using (Html.BeginForm() { @Html.AntiForgeryToken() ... }" ?  You can scaffold the View out and list the Bindings you would like inside of the Controller's POST method with the name you choose.

Comment: @CodeBreaker I am not sure what you just said. I am new to MVC. Any doc or something I can reference? What is the difference between HTML.BeginForm and the way I am doing it?

Comment: No worries!  Please take a look at the MS Doc found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx.  It gives a little context into the BeginForm() method and the arguments you can pass into it.  Essentially, BeginForm() in a Razor View file will create the HTML form for you, though it makes it EXTREMELY easy to pass the Action name, Controller name, etc. and use Html.SelectList or Html.SelectListFor to pass data back to the controller based on the Select List name in the View. I will create an Answer to help explain, too.

Comment: If you can, experiment using the Scaffolded Item function for the MVC project by right-clicking on the Views folder within the project and then hovering over "Add >" and clicking "New Scaffolded Item..." option in the menu.  This will automatically build out all of the Views as well as the Controller and Actions either for a Model Item (Table object, View Model, etc.) or it will create a blank Controller and Views for you to fill out yourself.  Scaffolded Items are awesome if you have done the work ahead of time to be sure your Model (database Table structures, View Models, etc.) is strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default framework behavior of `return View()` is to return a view with the same name as the currently-executing action.  Which is `TestAction`.  The error is telling you that no such view was found.

You have a couple of options.  You can either **create the view**, or you can return something else.  For example, if you want to redirect back to the `Index` then you can return a redirect result:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

You *could* also specify the `Index` view in the response:

```
return View("Index");
```

*However*, keep in mind that the URL will still be for `TestAction` and *not* for `Index`, which could result in unexpected changes to behavior if you're not aware of this.

---

**Edit:** Based on comments on this answer, it sounds like what you actually want is to build a *pair* of actions which generally operate on the same view.  This isn't particularly common for an *index* view, but is very common for *edit* views.  The only difference is semantics, structurally the concept works anywhere.

Consider two actions:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // just show the page
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SQL_Blocks_App.Models.DropdownList SelectedValue)
{
    // receive data from the page
    // perform some operation
    // and show the page again
    return View();
}
```

Requests between these two actions would differ only by the HTTP verb (GET or POST), not by the action name on the URL.  That name would always be "Index".  But when the form on the index view is submitted via POST and has a "SelectedValue", the second action is invoked instead of the first.

In that second action you would perform your database interaction, gather whatever data you needed, and if necessary include a model or some additional data in the response.

Comment: I added more info at the bottom of the post just to clarify. I don't want a new view just want to return to index with results.

Comment: @Abdul: What results?  Currently there are no "results" being sent to any view, whether that view exists or not.  A redirect can contain information, though be aware that information would be on the URL query string.  Conversely you could rename `TestAction` to an overload of `Index` with an `[HttpPost]` attribute and then you're only ever dealing with one action name.  From the client's perspective that would look like a page that posts to itself, which is very common.

Comment: I edited my post previously not sure if you saw the new info at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: @Abdul: In that case it sounds like what you probably want to do is rename your `TestAction` to `Index` and keep everything on the same URL.  This isn't necessarily common for an *index* action/view, but is very common for something like an "edit" action/view.  Whereas the `HttpGet` version of the action just returns the form, and the `HttpPost` version of the action accepts the form values and performs some logic before returning the form again.

Comment: I tried this and it works. Only thing that is weird is when I try to print SelectedValue it just prints "SQL_Blocks_App.Models.DropdownList" not the actual value that was selected. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Abdul: How are you trying to print it?  The default string representation for any reference object is the type name for that object.  If you want to print something specific, you'd either have to override `.ToString()` on the object's class definition or output the specific values from the object directly.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(SelectedValue); I was trying this. So should I do  
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ToString(SelectedValue));?

Comment: @Abdul: Well, if you define a `ToString()` helper method in the class where you write that line, sure.  But that's an unusual approach.  Normally one would either output the value: `SelectedValue.SelectedValue` (Note: Naming is important.  Your variable of type `DropDownList` has the same name as its only property.  This may lead to confusion.)  *Or* you could override `.ToString()` in your `DropDownList` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to index action, and pass the parameters along

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("TestAction")]
public ActionResult TestAction(SQL_Blocks_App.Models.DropdownList _selectedValue)
{

    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(SelectedValue);



    return RedirectToAction("Index", "[Controller]", new {@_selectedValue = _selectedValue });
}
```

and then your Index method should accept the parameter.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(SQL_Blocks_App.Models.DropdownList _selectedValue)
{
  //use _selectedValue
}
```

I would recommend using another method other than your index, or make Dropdownlist nullable/set a default for it.

Answer (score 0):

You TestAction method is returning to a View. Make sure View TestAction.cshtml exists and is in the Home folder.